# Strange behavior of HSQLDB and group by

Tags: junit, aggregate-functions, hsqldb, dbunit

I am using HSQLDB for writing junits and my query is like this:

```
String queryStr = "from ManualUrlBatchModel where status IN(:status) group by batchUser order by creationTime";
        Query query = getSession(requestType).createQuery(queryStr);
        query.setParameterList("status", status);
```

I am retrieving one batch per user in the given status (depending on creation time FIFO order).

It runs fine for end to end testing but fails while writing junits.

Exception says:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Not in aggregate function or group by clause: org.hsqldb.Expression@164f8d4 in statement [select manualurlb0_.manual_url_batch_id as manual1_7_, manualurlb0_.creation_time as creation2_7_, manualurlb0_.modification_time as modifica3_7_, manualurlb0_.attribute_list as attribute4_7_, manualurlb0_.batch_name as batch5_7_, manualurlb0_.batch_user as batch6_7_, manualurlb0_.input_s3_key as input7_7_, manualurlb0_.locale as locale7_, manualurlb0_.notify_when_complete as notify9_7_, manualurlb0_.output_s3_key as output10_7_, manualurlb0_.processed_url_count as processed11_7_, manualurlb0_.s3_bucket as s12_7_, manualurlb0_.status as status7_, manualurlb0_.submitted_url_count as submitted14_7_, manualurlb0_.total_url_count as total15_7_ from csi_manual_url_batch manualurlb0_ where manualurlb0_.status in (? , ?) group by manualurlb0_.batch_user order by manualurlb0_.creation_time]
    [junit]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
```

I found couple of things on net:

1. GROUP BY doesn't work in HSQLDB if group by isnot on the basis of string.
2. GROUP BY doesn't work the way I have used (select * .... group by COL1).

I am sure people would have faced this issue earlier, what did you guys do then (apart from not writing the junits :))?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In standard SQL, the group by clause must contain every selected value except the ones which are aggregate functions.

```
select a, b, c, d, sum(e) from table group by a -- INVALID
select a, b, c, d, sum(e) from table group by a, b  -- INVALID
select a, b, c, d, sum(e) from table group by a, b, c  -- INVALID
select a, b, c, d, sum(e) from table group by a, b, c, d -- VALID
```

The query generated by Hibernate is thus invalid, and AFAIK, the only possible way to make a group by HQL query work is to list every scalar column you want to select explicitely (see https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1615):

```
 select m.foo, m.bar, m.creationTime, m.batchUser  
 from ManualUrlBatchModel m 
 where m.status IN(:status) 
 group by m.foo, m.bar, m.creationTime, m.batchUser 
 order by m.creationTime
```

If your original query works with MySQL, it's because MySQL doesn't respect the SQL standard, and allows queries with `group by` not listing every selected column. I would suggest not relying on this "feature", using the same database in tests and in production, and using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL.

Comment: There is accually one problem with this. If, for example, `foo` is an entity than query will make join and add new clumns from joined table.

Answer (score 1):

you could also aggregate all select values you dont want to group by as well:

for example `select a, sum(b), sum(c), sum(d), sum(e) from table group by a; -- VALID`